Incompatibility of python version 3.11.4 with scipy
I just learned python, my python version is 3.11.4 and scipy version 1.13.0 is installed, when the program is run it gives the error "cannot import name 'triu' from 'scipy.linalg'", how to fix this error do i
I could not do anything

What else are you using that requires the scipy version  of triu instead of the numpy one?

I don't think the python version is the problem here.

basically triu is deprecated and was removed in 1.13, easiest solution is changing scipy version to before 1.13
to select the version you run :
pip install scipy==1.12


Thank you for your answer
I did this but my problem is still not solved

in that case could you please add the code that run this error ?
